# How to define mongodb Text Indexes in mgo with weights

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to create text indexes with weights but I couldn't figure out how to do by reading API docs.

How can I build indexes as below in mgo.

```
db.products.createIndex({
  "primaryCategoryIndexes": "text",
  "secondaryCategoryIndexes": "text",
  "brandIndex": "text",
  "primaryTitleIndexes": "text",
  "secondaryTitleIndexes": "text",
  "indexCycleId": "text"
  }, {
    "weights": {
      "primaryCategoryIndexes":10,
      "secondaryCategoryIndexes": 5,
      "brandIndex": 5,
      "primaryTitleIndexes": 5,
      "secondaryTitleIndexes": 5, 
      "indexCycleId": 5
  })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a text index in mongodb with golang and the mgo library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592864/how-do-i-create-a-text-index-in-mongodb-with-golang-and-the-mgo-library)

Comment: @Marc thank you for pointing out but that answer does not include weights.

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason the direct answer to this question in the comment is deleted. I try not to get on it but I think it is the best to post the answer back.

It is possible to use a field in the `mgo.Index` to get the work done. However some version of my does not support it.

Please read the manual:
https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Index

```
type Index struct {
    Key        []string // Index key fields; prefix name with dash (-) for descending order
    Unique     bool     // Prevent two documents from having the same index key
    DropDups   bool     // Drop documents with the same index key as a previously indexed one
    Background bool     // Build index in background and return immediately
    Sparse     bool     // Only index documents containing the Key fields

    // If ExpireAfter is defined the server will periodically delete
    // documents with indexed time.Time older than the provided delta.
    ExpireAfter time.Duration

    // Name holds the stored index name. On creation if this field is unset it is
    // computed by EnsureIndex based on the index key.
    Name string

    // Properties for spatial indexes.
    //
    // Min and Max were improperly typed as int when they should have been
    // floats.  To preserve backwards compatibility they are still typed as
    // int and the following two fields enable reading and writing the same
    // fields as float numbers. In mgo.v3, these fields will be dropped and
    // Min/Max will become floats.
    Min, Max   int
    Minf, Maxf float64
    BucketSize float64
    Bits       int

    // Properties for text indexes.
    DefaultLanguage  string
    LanguageOverride string

    // Weights defines the significance of provided fields relative to other
    // fields in a text index. The score for a given word in a document is derived
    // from the weighted sum of the frequency for each of the indexed fields in
    // that document. The default field weight is 1.
    Weights map[string]int

    // Collation defines the collation to use for the index.
    Collation *Collation
}
```

By the way, regarding golang, there are godoc.org and go-serach.org for searching go libs and they generally outperform Google.

Comment: https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Index Do Ctrl+F and paste "Weights" please go on...

Comment: Now I know why I didn't saw the Weights field before. Because it isn't even present in the first place. Because when you type "mgo Index" to the google you get this documentation. Until now I've thought that I missed it. Oh man! This relieved me so much. I have to thank to your obsession to. If you weren't  so obsessed I wouldn't figured out this fact and was thinking that you could probably right. Can you imagine that.

Comment: I did not expect that. I apologize for being too harsh on you. Yet I suggest next time, to avoid such situations, please attach what you have tried in questions, as stack overflow guidelines suggest.

Comment: The link is godoc to.

Comment: I mean, godoc has a search engine and you can search directly from it.